# java client server security

Tags: java, security, client-server

In our old project, we had WCF service with message security (certificate and login/password) and WPF client. Now we need something similar (JavaFX client and server) on the Java. Also, we need a way to get current logged user on the server side inside any of the methods (something like `ServiceSecurityContext.Current.PrimaryIdentity.Name` in WCF), and at a user authentication we need access to entities of our server and config files (like in `UserNamePasswordValidator` in WCF).

What is a correct way to get it all in Java? We tried `JAX-WS`, remote `EJB` call, `RMI`. It all working similar without security, but what can we expect on the next step? And which way give us more opportunities in the future?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We found solution for us in [Spring Remoting](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html). Now we use `Spring's HTTP invoker`

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Apache Shiro](http://shiro.apache.org/) .  It has credentials-based Authentication with sessions management through cookies (can integrate with user table from DB or LDAP etc), User Authorization, input validation and many other features.  I've used it with great success.

Comment: Looks interesting. But my question about interaction way between client and server, which support our security requirements and can give us more opportunities and flexibility in Java World. Today we could implement `SOAP` service with all we need, but maybe other ways (`EJB`, `RMI` or something else) is better. We're just dilettantes right now, but we need make a choice. Sorry, if my first question had foggy..

Comment: none of these protocols have security features built-in.  I can tell you the most popular one is REST, touted as simple and easy to implement.  You still have to manually add authentication, authrization etc